# Eventlistener firing twice

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to call the function after leaving the textbox and it is working somewhat but instead of the function just checking for letters in the first name textbox it will call the entire function and I think it is what is causing my code to fire both lines, I am not sure how to make it so that the portion of code specified for the input box is called instead of the whole thing. I thought by specifiying the element name it will only focus on that particular textbox but it is not the case. Also in browser it will fire only twice instead of four times like it does in this code snippet runner.

```js
function validateData() {
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

  var firstName = document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0];
  if (firstName.value.match(letters)) {
    alert("Yes")
  } else {
    alert("No")
  }

  var lastName = document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0];
  if (lastName.value.match(letters)) {
    alert("Yes2")
  } else {
    alert("No2")
  }
}
document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].addEventListener('blur', validateData);
document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].addEventListener('blur', validateData);
```

```css
#prompt {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#prompt2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.input:focus+#prompt {
  color: #000;
}

.input:focus+#prompt2 {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/process.js"></script>
  <title>Info</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend> Personal Information</legend>

      First Name: <br>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" class="input" onfocusout="validateData()">
      <span id="prompt">Please enter first name</span>
      <br> Last Name: <br>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" class="input" onfocusout="validateData()">
      <span id="prompt2">Please enter last name</span>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not because you are calling it onfocusout too?

Comment: Yeah, it might be an idea to remove the inline `onfocusout` and just use your `eventlistener`, but make it more specific like so: `document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].addEventListener('blur focusout', validateData);`

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two event listeners placed on this code though.

More so, you have two ifs which mean after running the first if-else statement, it should go-ahead to run the other if-else.

Going by your code, why not try something like:

```
function validateData(content, validationType) {
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if(validationType === 'firstname') {
   if (content.match(letters)) {
    alert("Yes")
   } else {
    alert("No")
   }
  }
  else if(validationType === 'lastname') {
   if (content.match(letters)) {
    alert("Yes2")
   } else {
    alert("No2")
   }
  }
 }

document.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].addEventListener('blur', () =>  validateData(this.value, "firstname"));
document.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].addEventListener('blur', () =>  validateData(this.value, "lastname"));
```

Comment: can you explain what () =>  validateData("firstname") does because I don't really understand how it works, does it just call the validateData function when I move away from the textbox?

Comment: Hello, that's actually a short-hand to returning a function in another function.

Comment: I didn't want to declare a complete function that executes/return the "validateData" function.

Comment: And yes, it does call the validateData function when you move out of the textbox